# Resizable stops working on div after its contents are updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using jQuery UI's `resizable` function to make a div (bootstrap panel) that displays the contents of the file uploaded resizable. Resizable works on the div initially but after I update it with the contents of the file uploaded it stops working and the resizable cursor doesn't appear. This behavior can be observed in the snippet below and [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oc032cqx/).

```js
$("#filePreview").resizable({
  handles: "n, s",
  minHeight: 100
});

function readFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = readSuccess;

  function readSuccess(evt) {
    $('#filePreview').text(evt.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

$(document).on('change', '#inputFile', function() {
  readFile(this.files[0]);
});
```

```css
.preview-panel {
  white-space: pre-line;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputFile">File Input</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputFile">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">File Preview</div>
    <div class="panel-body preview-panel" id="filePreview"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have seen [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978358/make-resizable-a-dynamically-add-div) on [resizable for dynamically added elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512442/apply-jqueryui-resizable-widget-to-dynamically-created-elements) and tried reinitializing resizable after the div is updated with the new file content but [it didn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/oc032cqx/1/). How do I make `resizable` work on the div even after its content changes to display the preview of the last uploaded file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried "destroying" the resizable `div` before setting the text and then re-initializing it after setting the text?

```
function readFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = readSuccess;

  function readSuccess(evt) {
    $('#filePreview').resizable('destroy');
    $('#filePreview').text(evt.target.result);
    $("#filePreview").resizable({
      handles: "n, s",
      minHeight: 100
    });
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

I don't know if this is a quirk of the plugin, but you have to scroll to the top of the content in the `div` in order to see/use the resizable "handles".

**EDIT:** To fix the issue with the "handle" losing its position when scrolling, I've added a helper function to add a `top` value using the the `scrollTop` value of `#filePreview` + the `height` of the `.preview-panel` + an additional offset (`27px` in this case). Whenever the `scroll` event is triggered on `#filePreview`, I'm adjusting the position of the handle accordingly.

```
$("#filePreview").on('scroll', function() {
  adjustHandlePosition();
});

function adjustHandlePosition() {
  $('.ui-resizable-s').css('top', ($("#filePreview").scrollTop() + $('.preview-panel').height() + 27) + "px");
}
```

The `adjustHandlePosition()` method is also being called when the `resize` event occurs for `#filePreview`:

```
$("#filePreview").resizable({
  handles: "n, s",
  minHeight: 100,
  resize: function(event, ui) {
    adjustHandlePosition();
  }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/oc032cqx/6/)**

Comment: Just tired destroy. It is working most of the time but sometimes resizable is not working even with destroy.

Comment: What if you scroll to the top of the div and then try to resize? The position of the handle doesn't change when you scroll.

Comment: Strange sometimes even without scrolling to the to its working and sometimes its not. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Not sure. I'll take another look when I have time. I'll get back to you if I make any progress.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ is working where I set scrollTop(0) for the div and it works.

Comment: No but its works everytime a new file is uploaded where the vertical scroll goes back to the top automatically.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I mentioned in my answer. I've not had time to figure out a solution as I'm at work, but I'll have time later on.

Comment: @Ram I've updated my answer and fiddle with a fix that should solve the outstanding issue. Please let me know if there are any issues with the update.

Comment: What exactly is 27px representing here? Looks like in cases when the file content is too wide for the panel the horizontal scroll comes up and when the horizontal scroll is displayed the resize handle is not being displayed.

Comment: Without the additional 27px, the handle appears above where it should be. The offset ensures the handle appears at the bottom of the panel.

Comment: I've added some more code that adds an offset conditionally (based on the `scrollWidth` and `clientWidth`). It may need some tweaking in terms of the offset value, but it works on the whole. Please see the updated fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, it works now even with the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: No probs. Happy to help.